# Counting percentage of true elements in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, boolean, percentage

```
class Constituency < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :votes
end

class Vote <ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :constituency
end
```

I have a database with votes and each vote has boolean attribute "valid_vote".
What I want to receive how many votes are in each constituency (in percent), but counting only valid votes. So 100% is all votes, where valid_vote == true.
Any ideas how should I write it?

Comment: Please demonstrate some wiliness to learn by showing the query you tried.

Comment: So you mean a scope like `Vote.where(valid_vote: true)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all the percentage of valid votes to all votes run:

```
all_votes_count = constituency.votes.count
valid_votes_count = constituency.votes.where(valid_vote: true).count
if all_votes_count > 0
  percent = valid_notes_count / all_votes_count
else
  puts "no votes"
end
```

Comment: Careful with potentially dividing by zero.

Comment: `Constituency.votes` isn't a method, you need to get a `Constituency` instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a single SQL query like this:

```
h = votes.group(:valid_vote).count
percentage = 100.0 * h[true] / h.values.sum rescue 0
```